# Android/IOS browser. prevent default keyboard from showing on a field focus (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I am writing a custom 'component' in javascript, whereas I dont want the native keyboard to pop open while focusing on an input element.
Can someone explain the best way to do this ?
Thanks!

Comment: How will the the user input the info? Speaking?

Comment: Don't use an `<input>` or `<textarea>` but rather a different element?

Comment: not using input or textarea would work too. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. The reason why I am doing this is that the HTML5 'date' input type is very buggy (on Android), and not acceptable for our users.
So instead of using the native date, i changed it to a regular input. then on the 'focus' event I stop propogation and immediately blur it: IE:

```
focus: function(el, evt) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
                this.blur();
                openCustomComponent();
            }
```